# Here-Maps Android Premium SDK - where is mappedPosition?

Tags: android, here-api

I built a Route and I need the mappedPosition of my Waypoint. In iOS Premium SDK there is such a coordinate, in the Android Premium SDK I do not see such a coordinate. Where can I get a coordinate on the road that will fit my Waypoint?

Answer (score 2):

I found where to get the desired coordinate on the route

```
mapRoute.route.routeWaypoints[index].roadInfo.matchedCoordinate
```